# Call a static function inside array php

Tags: php, arrays, class, web, methods

How can I call a static function inside an array? I tried it but it gives me an `Constant expression contains invalid operations` I have two classes the Login class and Route class.

the Route class uses the Login::getJSFile() inside the array $routes but gives an error

Here is my code:

```
class Route
{
    private static $routes = [
        "login"                     => [
            "add_to_menu"            => false,
            "class"                  => "login-page",
            "component"              => [],
            "css"                    => ["/css/form", "/css/login"],
            "default"                => true,
            "display_footer_menu"    => true,
            "display_header_menu"    => false,
            "enable_authentication"  => true,
            "enable_permission"      => false,
            "form"                   => true,
            "icon"                   => "<i class='fa fa-sign-in fa-fw'></i>",
            "js"                     => Login::getJSFile(),
            "layout"                 => "pages/login.php",
            "list"                   => false,
            "menu_order"             => null,
            "menu_type"              => null,
            "name"                   => "Login",
            "no_layout"              => "pages/no-layout.php",
            "parent"                 => "",
            "php"                    => ["/php/login"],
            "require_authentication" => false,
            "require_permission"     => false,
            "url"                    => "/login/"
        ]
    ];
}


class Login
{
    private static $login_routes = [
        "administrator" => [
            "default"   => false,
            "id"        => "administrator",
            "js"        => [],
            "layout"    => "pages/components/login/administrator.php",
            "name"      => "Administrator",
            "no_layout" => "pages/no-layout.php",
            "url"       => "administrator"
        ],
        "student"       => [
            "default"   => true,
            "id"        => "student",
            "js"        => ["/lib/Inputmask-3.x/dist/min/jquery.inputmask.bundle.min", "/js/components/login/student"],
            "layout"    => "pages/components/login/student.php",
            "name"      => "Student",
            "no_layout" => "pages/no-layout.php",
            "url"       => "student"
        ]
    ];

    public static function getJSFile()
    {
        echo self::$login_routes[self::getCurrent()]["js"];
    }
}
```

Comment: do you want to store function inside array?

Comment: yes but the function resides on class "Login" so I used Login::getJSFile()

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.forward-static-call-array.php

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you intend on using this, but you could harness variable variables:

```
$login = ${$a['login']['js']};
```

An example/POC below:

```
class Login {

    function test() { echo 'DERP TEST DERP';}
}

$a = [
    'login' => [
        'js' => Login::test()    
    ]
];

$login = ${$a['login']['js']};
```

<sup>*This isn't the nicest way of doing it, but it achieves what's required. I do* (***HIGHLY***) *recommend you look at alternatives within your code base to handle this properly.*</sup>

[**Example/Demo**](https://www.tehplayground.com/cVrOAoJTkdILeisb)

Comment: What if the $a is inside another class? I tried it but gives me error.

Comment: @Mr.Programmer Can you show your complete code. (*update your answer with it.*)